# Image download with registered user in django

Tags: python, django

i have image field in my model just like that..

```
 class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField()
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True,auto_now = False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 80 , blank = False , null = True)
    approved_by = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and i have make another model where the Photo model is foreign key

```
class PhotoDownload(models.Model):
    dowloaded_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
```

first,i want to make a view where all the uploaded image will be shown with a download link for each image,then when the user click the link it will download automatically,how can i do that,in mention, i am very new in django,so i have no idea about this.

Comment: There is plenty of documentation and Q&A are available on that. Show us your code any specific problem that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

see django models API

At first, you should know how the database store and read photos

go to your project directory

run

```
python manage.py shell
>>from appname.models import Photo
>>Photo.objects.all()
>>Photo.objects.create(name=....)
```

more see here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/

Then you may know how urls work
url(r'^(.+)$', 'mysite.views.photo', name='photo-list'),

views function, templates

you need learn these.

You can download some django packages from github to see how others write

An example:
http://lightbird.net/dbe/photo2.html

Comment: Sorry WeizhongTu ,your answer is not the answer what i am searching for.